# Get window titles of minimized windows using Core Graphics?

Tags: swift, macos, core-graphics

I am using Core Graphics to read window titles from other processes.

```
@objc public func getWindowDetailsByPid(_ pid: pid_t) -> NSDictionary? {
    guard let windowList = CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo([.optionOnScreenOnly], kCGNullWindowID) as NSArray? else { return nil }
    
    for case let window as NSDictionary in windowList {
        if let windowPID = window[kCGWindowOwnerPID as String] as? Int, windowPID == pid {
            let windowTitle = window[kCGWindowName as String] as? String ?? ""
            if let windowNumber = window[kCGWindowNumber as String] as? NSNumber {
                let windowId = windowNumber.uint32Value
                let windowOwnerName = window[kCGWindowOwnerName as String] as? String ?? ""
                return ["windowOwner":windowOwnerName, "windowTitle": windowTitle, "windowId": windowId]
            }
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

}

This works as long as the window is not minimized, since I have selected the `optionOnScreenOnly`. However, I also want to read the window titles of minimized windows, so I selected `optionAll`. Now, I am getting the information of all windows but no window titles at all, whether onscreen or minimized.

Is there a way to read the window titles of minimized windows?

I know it works with MacOS's Accessibility API, but the problem there is that there is no way to get the window ID and I absolutely need the window ID to be able to assign window titles to a specific ID.

Why `optionAll` doesn't work and is there a other way to get the window titles and IDs of minimized windows?